# Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getPath()

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony6

I'm new with symfony and I'm trying to create a delete button for the posted comments in my ArticleController.

I created my twig form which looks like this :

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ path('app_comment_delete', {'article_id': article.id}, {'comment_id': comment.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ comment.id) }}">
    <button id="delete-comment" class="position-absolute end-0 me-1 top-0 mt-1 btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i></button>
</form>
```

Then created my route in my Controller like this :

```php
    #[Route('/{article_id}/comment/{comment_id}', name: 'app_article_delete', methods: ['POST'])]
    #[ParamConverter('article', options: ['mapping' => ['article_id' => 'id']])]
    #[ParamConverter('comment', options: ['mapping' => ['comment_id' => 'id']])]
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]
    public function deleteComment(Request $request, Comment $comment, CommentRepository $commentRepository): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$comment->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $commentRepository->remove($comment, true);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_article_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
```

And I get this error :

```php
Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #3 ($relative) must be of type bool, array given, called in /var/www/var/cache/dev/twig/a2/a2cf7154143c694ab6758c7e828e13fb.php on line 44
```

I don't understand why symfony asks me about a #3 argument, I'm only passing the article_id and the comment_id.

Hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try by grouping your properties in a single object: `{{ path('app_comment_delete', {'article_id': article.id, 'comment_id': comment.id}) }}`

Comment: Seems a bit strange that a route for deleting a comment was named `app_article_delete`.  The command `bin/console debug:router` can often help with these sorts of things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay thanks to [yolenoyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271687/yolenoyer) and [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad) I found an answer to my problem.

First my route in my Controller was called :

```php
app_article_delete
```

So I renamed it to :

```php
app_comment_delete
```

Then I edited my ParamConverters because they weren't right and I also added my Entities so that Symfony doesn't mix them up :

```php
#[Route('/{article_id}/comment/{comment_id}', name: 'app_comment_delete', methods: ['POST'])]
#[ParamConverter('article_id', options: ['mapping' => ['id' => 'article']])]
#[ParamConverter('comment_id', options: ['mapping' => ['id' => 'comment']])]
#[Entity('article', expr: 'repository.find(article_id)')]
#[Entity('comment', expr: 'repository.find(comment_id)')]
#[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]
```

Finally I grouped my path properties in my twig form :

```
action="{{ path('app_comment_delete', {'article_id': article.id, 'comment_id': comment.id}) }}"
```

Now it seems to work just fine!

PS : I also deleted the mention 'delete' of my csrf_token value in my twig form and my Controller. Otherwise the function isCsrfTokenValid() wouldn't work. I have no idea why though.